# Moving header down in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to learn HTML and CSS, but have run into a tiny stumbling block.

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing My HTML and CSS</title>
    <style>

        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .header {
            background-color: black;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .header h1 {
            margin-top: 0;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .sidebar {
            background-color: #ebebeb;
            position: absolute;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100%;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <div class="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

which can be ran [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhzgoxm6/).

I want to have the `<h1>Hello, World!</h1>` in the center of the `.header`. I've tried playing with the `margin-top` in `.header h1`, but it moves the entire `.header`.

Sorry for such a simple question -- I'm a complete newbie.

Comment: to use line-height:100px  on .header h1 its works..

Comment: Use line-height property to 100px means that the text will be centered vertically in the middle of a row.

Comment: You can also use header as `display:table;` and `.header h1` as `display:table-cell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your're not planning to add more elements to the header, you can just add *line-height: 100px;* to the *.header h1* ruleset. That's it...

Vertical align can be tricky, if you don't want to mess around with a lot of code, this is the shortest way to accomplish it. As a general rule, to center text vertically into an element, just make its line-height equals to the element's height (unless you have some padding or margin changing stuff).

Answer (score 1):

Use line-height instead as following:

```
.header {
            background-color: black;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            line-height:2;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhzgoxm6/1/)

or you can try this using

```
.header{
line-height:3;
   }
```